# Clear Label text used in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, uistoryboard

Wondering if anyone know hows to complete the following...

In a `Storyboard` I set my Labels with dummy text, they are not Static text. For example 'User1 Username'.

What I would to know if there is a setting to clear the value of this label when it is loaded by the view. I have some other code that runs off and collects the relevant information. However, it might take a few seconds so a HUD is shown to the user whilst it loads.

Of course in the background of the HUD you can see the example text shown. I know in `viewDidLoad` I could simply clear all the label texts setting them back to `@""`, but is there no setting in the storyboard or anything for this?

Comment: Once you are done with layouting them, you could remove the dummy text?

Comment: Not Ideal, using the storyboard is a nice way to view what is expected. I guess as I suggest and per the 'hungry for points' answer below you just have to set them to nil...

Comment: If you want to view what you expected and you expect an empty string, then you should in fact set it to empty in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use *User Defined Runtime Attributes* to achieve this. Simply set "text" attribute for any *UILabel*, *UITextField* or *UITextView* to get what you want:

[image: Using Storyboard runtime attributes to clear label text]

KVC and runtime attributes are really powerfull when working with Storyboard (e.g. did you know that you can set "layer.cornerRadius" attribute to any UIView to get *rounded* corners?).

Comment: About rounded corners with runtime attributes check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626264

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to do it.
You would have to set the text of the `UILabel` manually in the `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: I suggested this in my question there is no need to answer with the same