# Removing text label/button on compile time/runtime on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to know if there are any way to remove a button text or label text on compile time.

I have a view which download the content data from server, so meanwhile the request is happening I would like to have empty texts, and I would like to keep the text I am using on xcode, just on Xcode, in order to make easy find views and have more descriptive views on my Xcode while developing.

Right now for each view that I want to do that, I'm using "User defined runtime attributes", to set to the text value to empty string, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I will need to do that for each element, and when data is back from server put back to 1, more complex than use "User defined runtime attributes"

Answer (score 1):

set text empty on viewWillAppear method

```
    [btnDontHaveAnAccountYet setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

and when you get response than reset the button title.

problem solve no need to set runtime text.

**OR ELSE**

just keep blank button text when you put it in xib/Viewcontroller.

you can use what ever you like both are easy and both are working.

Comment: About the first option, I would like to void need to write a line for each view that I want to clean, for that the "User defined runtime attributes" is cleaner/simple,  I looking for something more "clean", maybe using the interface builder, like the constraint option "Remove at build time". About the second, as I said, I want to keep text on xib/viewcontroller to make easy when working on the view, otherwise I will have a view with "transparent" elements.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self removeLabelsFrom:self.view];
}

- (void) removeLabelsFrom:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button;
            button = (UIButton *)subView;
            [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *label;
                label = (UILabel *)subView;
                label.text = @"";
            } else {
                if (subView.subviews.count > 0) {
                    [self removeLabelsFrom:subView];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of [Clear Label text used in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115410/clear-label-text-used-in-storyboard)

set the "text" property to en empty string in the user defined runtime attributes.