# What's currently the "correct" way to set a UIView's corner radius?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Setting a `UIView`'s corner radius can be done the following ways:

1. Set the `layer`'s `cornerRadius` property:

   ```
   view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
   view.layer.masksToBounds = true;
   ```
2. Apply a mask:

   ```
   func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
       let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
       let mask = CAShapeLayer()
       mask.path = path.cgPath
       self.layer.mask = mask
   }
   ```
3. Override `draw(_:)`:

   ```
   func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       // Size of rounded rectangle
       let rectWidth = rect.width
       let rectHeight = rect.height

       // Find center of actual frame to set rectangle in middle
       let xf: CGFloat = (self.frame.width  - rectWidth)  / 2
       let yf: CGFloat = (self.frame.height - rectHeight) / 2

       let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
       ctx.saveGState()

       let rect = CGRect(x: xf, y: yf, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight)
       let clipPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rectCornerRadius).cgPath

       ctx.addPath(clipPath)
       ctx.setFillColor(rectBgColor.cgColor)

       ctx.closePath()
       ctx.fillPath()
       ctx.restoreGState()
   }
   ```

Which of these is generally considered to be the "correct" way of implementing rounded corners on a `UIView`, accounting for the following criteria:

- configuration (some corners may be rounded while others are not)
- animation (can you animate the `cornerRadius` changing)
- flexibility (does it break third party libraries or masks you have already applied)
- readability (how concise/reusable is the solution)
- speed (does it negatively impact performance)

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistency, I just grabbed the shortest examples I could find online for each option. Feel free to edit with Swift3.

Comment: In addition to all answers we can use 'CACornerMask' from iOS 11 to easily set corner radius to view for selected corners.

Comment: By the way, if you do use `draw(_:)`, never use `frame` (which is in the superview’s coordinate system). Use `bounds` (which is in the view’s own coordinate system).

Answer (score 17):

Note that I don't know what's currently the “correct” way to set a UIView's corner radius.

What I prefer to do is to use Interface Builder as much as possible without having extra code which this approach shows and is reliable to my experience.

---

**From iOS 11 upwards**

you can use user-defined runtime attributes in the `Identity inspector` of the `Interface Builder` by setting the following properties:

```
layer.cornerRadius
layer.maskedCorners
layer.masksToBounds
```

According to the [documentation of the CACornerMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cacornermask?language=objc) you can see that the `maskedCorners` property is in fact a `NSUInteger` data type and you're allowed to set the following values:

```
kCALayerMinXMinYCorner = 1U << 0
kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner = 1U << 1
kCALayerMinXMaxYCorner = 1U << 2
kCALayerMaxXMaxYCorner = 1U << 3
```

Since you're allowed to `bitwise OR` those masks together you only have to "calculate" the resulting integer of that bitwise OR of what you actually need.

Therefore set the following number (integer) values for the `maskedCorners` property to get rounded corners:

```
 0 = no corner is being rounded
 1 = top left corner rounded only
 2 = top right corner rounded only
 3 = top left and top right corners rounded only
 4 = bottom left corner rounded only
 5 = top left and bottom left corners rounded only
 6 = top right and bottom left corners rounded only
 7 = top left, top right and bottom left corners rounded only
 8 = bottom right corner rounded only
 9 = top left and bottom right corners rounded only
10 = top right and bottom right corners rounded only
11 = top left, top right and bottom right corners rounded only
12 = bottom left and bottom right corners rounded only
13 = top left, bottom left and bottom right corners rounded only
14 = top right, bottom left and bottom right corners rounded only
15 = all corners rounded
```

**Example:** If you want to set the corner radius for the **top-left** and the **top-right** corners of a UIView you would use those attributes:

[image: top-left and top-right corner of a UIView]

Comment: Didn't quite get how does this answer the question

Comment: @vahotm added explanation

Answer (score 10):

Re your three options:

1. Using `CALayer` existing properties: This is an easy (and likely the most efficient) solution for simple corner masking. It is animatable, too. In iOS 11 and later, you can pick which corners are to be masked.
2. Re custom `CAShapeLayer` masks: This is nice approach if the corner masking is not simple corner rounding but some arbitrary path. You have to be cautious to make sure to update this mask if the `frame` changes (e.g. update the path in [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) of view or in [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) of controller).

   Admittedly, if you want to do a very graceful animation as the view’s `frame` changes, that takes a little more work. But, as I point out above, simply responding to frame changes in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is quite simple and takes care of it if you are not too worried about the corner rounding mid-animation.
3. Re custom [`draw(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw): This is more work than it is worth and you are probably not enjoying optimizations that Apple’s team may have done behind the scenes (e.g. what if subsequent `draw` calls are only drawing a portion of the full `bounds`; your code is redrawing the whole thing regardless).

I would suggest option 1 for simple cases, and option 2 if you need more control than option 1 can offer. But there is no “best” approach: It depends upon what you need and how much work you are willing to go through.

Comment: I believe that 3 won't round the subviews though. It's just drawing an ellipse.

Comment: Well, not an ellipse, but a rounded rect. But you're right, it's just filling that path, not cropping to that path. And it's not even doing that right. But it could easily be fixed to crop whatever else this particular view's `draw(_:)`  renders. (BTW, the first approach only crops subviews if you select "clip to bounds".)

Comment: @Rob How do you deal with animations/parallax effects (like in tvOS)? The only way I managed to make it fully working has been redrawing the image, clipping out the corners. Once done that, with clipsToBounds = false otherwise the scaled image gets clipped, I have to use "masksFocusEffectToContents = true". Which works fine, but I doubt it is how Apple is doing it in apps like Movies.

Comment: I am using 2 (or 1 on ios 12) but only the left side is rounded correctly, the right side is not, and the background is not updated correctly, presumably due to the updating of the bounds/frame to be wider (and thereafter the masking): https://imgur.com/a/BmP6cu7 The code to round the radius is currently inside `layoutSubviews`. Seems like others has the same issue as well from the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255791/321629

Comment: Fixed it as I had to call `self.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.layoutIfNeeded()` in order to update the the child view bounds (I'm also using autolayout) and then it gets the correct updated bound data.

Answer (score 9):

I did a couple of test with iOS 11 or lower version and the best practice I discovered for me to round a specific or all corners, you can do with the next code.

```
// Full size
CGSize vSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

// Object
UIView *viewTest = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, vSize.width, vSize.height)];
[viewTest setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[viewTest setBackgroundColor: [UIColor grayColor]];

// maskedCorners is only available in iOS 11
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [viewTest setClipsToBounds: YES];
    [viewTest.layer setCornerRadius: 10];

    // Only if you want to round the left and right top corners
    [viewTest.layer setMaskedCorners: kCALayerMinXMinYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner];
}
else {
    // The old way used in lower version
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayerObj = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [shapeLayerObj setPath: [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: viewTest.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath];

    [viewTest.layer setMask: shapeLayerObj];
}
```

- This code fix the problem with autoResizingMask doesn't work when it use the old way to round corners.
- Fix a bug with UIScrollView with round corners and setContentSize major to height of object.

The swift version it's something like this

```
let view = UIView()
view.clipsToBounds = true
view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
```

Comment: Yes is possible, if you want a swift version check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498892/different-cornerradius-for-each-corner-swift-3-ios but if you want the Objective-C version I can make it, cheers :)

Comment: I have tried this but only corner radius works no shadow display.  @Ladd.c

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the most comprehensive summary of all: http://texturegroup.org/docs/corner-rounding.html

My heuristic is that if the view doesn't need a high performance (e.g. it's not inside a table view cell), the easiest option is using CALayer's `cornerRadius`. If you need some more advanced corner radius or high performance, then it's better to explore other options.

Answer (score 1):

I go with the first one, it is the cleaner way of doing and you can do it in the IDE without code. Open the attributes inspector and then click on the Identity inspector and add under "User Defined Runtime attributes" those 2 properties:

[image]

Comment: Except this doesn't allow for the first criteria of rounding only certain corners.

Comment: agree with @rmaddy, not sure if we can add user-defined attributes to mask minXminY corners

Comment: @Naishta seems possible see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626264

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
  contView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
  contView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMinYCorner]
  contView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

this is the result just top left and top right corners